# GraphQL InputObjectType

Tags: graphql

**What will be the input object type for this object variable?**

```
let data = {
      companyId: "ABCD",
      source: "tally", 
      formDataId: "154",
      formData: [{
                    value: "02",
                    fieldPath: "voucher/sales"
                  },
                  {
                    value: "5o kgs",
                    fieldPath: "voucher/sales"
                  },
                  {
                    value: "soap"
                    fieldPath: "voucher/sales"
                  }],
      date: "2017-03-29"
 };
```

I'm confused with the value field because it has multiple types of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GraphQL input type for your data object could look like this:

```js
...

`
input SalePropertyInput {
  value: String!
  relatedProperty: String!
}

input SaleInput {
  companyId: ID!
  source: String!
  properties: [SalePropertyInput!]!
}
`

...
```

But i think before you start the mutation you should map the values from the form to the data you really need on the server. E.g. you don't need the `formDataId`. And i suggest you check the form you're using on the client that the field path can be mapped to some sort of sale property. Which can be used to differentiate the input on the server